# Make gdb.exe from gdb source code in Windows

Tags: gdb, makefile, codeblocks

How can i Make "gdb.exe" from gdb source code in Windows?

I have downloaded gdb-7.6 (GNU Debugger) source code (gdb-7.6.tar.bz2)
and then extract it.

I googled lot but i couldnt find explicit and clear commands for make "gdb.exe" from its source code.
There were some commands in its "README" file like

```
./configure
make
```

but it is not for windows (maybe those are for Linux, i don't know)

I need "gdb.exe" for CodeBlocks IDE,
by the way mingw and codeblocks are installed on my PC.
I will thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried building with GNU make/GCC?

Comment: Also, it appears that gdb is available in the setup package for [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26), so is there a reason you've not used that installer package?